# Error JQuery on Font Awesome Icon

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome

I am creating a JQuery sliding navigation using Font Awesome (SEE: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Now upon adding CSS since this is a third party web fonts icons I wonder how can I apply it to my own code using the + and - icon. I used image icons before but now I am planning to integrate it with web icons.

my jQuery code is.

```
$("#toggle > li > div").click(function(){
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#toggle ul').slideUp();  
        $("span.minus-btn").removeClass('minus-btn');
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});

$("#toggle > li > div").click(function() {

         $("#toggle > li > div").removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass('active');

if($(this).hasClass("active")){
       $("span.plus-btn", this).toggleClass('minus-btn');
         }
});
```

Now I am stock I don't even know how to fix the sizes of icons. Please help.

Here's the JQuery Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/SG7LZ/6/

Any great help + explanation please?

Please show me the solution on JSFiddle so that I can check on the code and results.

A big thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the same style to the `font-size` attribute used fot the main icons, so your css will look like:

```
span.plus-btn{
    float: right;
    font-size: 26px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 43px;
    margin-top: -34px;
    padding:0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Finally I have to rewrite your code to let the icon toggle works.

In the code I take a reference in a variable of the current menu icon `$currIcon=$(this).find("span.the-btn > i")` then I change all the icons, but not the current back in the compressed state (plus).

Now using toggleClass I siwtch plus/minus icons on the previously stored element `$currIcon`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/npNXT/

Comment: Great solution for this. Can u explain this part of the code to me?

    var $currIcon=$(this).find("span.the-btn > i")
    
    $("span.the-btn > i").not($currIcon).addClass('fa-plus').removeClass('fa-minus');
    
    $currIcon.toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
    
    $(this).next().slideToggle();

    $("#toggle > li > div").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');

});

Comment: Good. I'll explain it ASAP inside the answer

Comment: Ok so how does this part works?   

var $currIcon=$(this).find("span.the-btn > i")

Comment: I tired to explain it, check the answer; if you need more info ask them to me

Answer (score 0):

just use `fa-2x|fa-3x|fa-4x class`

see here examples:
[font-awesome-examples](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/)